# ng-container*ng-if=boolean returns content undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using `Angular2` and when I create a `boolean` to show differents contents on a page, I'm getting this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollToBottom' of undefined

If I remove the `booleans` doesn't crash, but if I do it does.

My `html` looks like this :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="startChat">

    <ion-header>
      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>{{channel}}</ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
        <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="{{image}}">
      </ion-avatar>    
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content class="has-header has-footer content-stable">

        <ion-infinite-scroll (infinite)="onScroll($event)">
          <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
        </ion-infinite-scroll> 

        <div *ngFor="let content of messages" class="message-wrapper">

          <div *ngIf="content.sender=='sender'">

            <img class="profile-pic left" src="{{image}}" />

            <div class="chat-bubble left">
              <div class="message-detail">
                <span>{{content.date | date:"dd/MM/yyyy h:mma"}}</span>
              </div>

              <div class="message" [innerHTML]="content.content">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="content.sender=='reciever'">
            <img class="profile-pic right" src="{{image}}" />
            <div class="chat-bubble right">
              <div class="message-detail">
                <span>{{content.date | date:"dd/MM/yyyy h:mma"}}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="message" [innerHTML]="content.content">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer>
      <form [formGroup]="messageForm" (ngSubmit)="sendMessage(messageForm.value)">
        <ion-toolbar position="bottom">
          <ion-textarea placeholder="Type your message here" formControlName="message" [(ngModel)]="message" (ngModelChange)="ngOnChanges($event)"></ion-textarea>
          <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only type="submit" [disabled]="!messageForm.valid"><ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon></button>
          </ion-buttons>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </form>
    </ion-footer>
  </ng-container>
```

if I remove the `startChat` variable it shows the page perfect, but at the time to change the view or put a `boolean` on `ng-container` it starts to crash...

This is the method that crashes

```
  scrollToTop() {
    var THIS = this.content;
    setTimeout(function () {
        THIS.scrollToBottom(); 
    }, 100);
  }
```

What I'm missing, can I use another component instead of `ng-container`? I tried to use `<div *ng-if=startChat>` and inside the `<ng-container>` it shows all but the `<ion-content>`

If I use the `<div>` tag to put inside the `<ng-container>` it shows this error

> main.js:1581 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollToBottom' of null

I `console.log(THIS)` and it shows the `content{}` not empty.

Comment: seems var content of your controller is undefined. can you show us the console log of this.content?

Comment: @DanielSeguraPérez edited my question replying your question

Comment: Oost the full relevant code of your component, please, it is unclear when the `scrollToTop` method is invoked

Comment: @ArmenVardanyan I guess the problem is, becaus eI have this :this.service.startTimer(params,this.functionThatcallScrollToTop.bind(this),this.onSynchronice); the function called functionThatcallScrollToTop changes the values of booleans and call scrollToTop()

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: No, I have the same problem

Comment: Share your component code. Show us what is 'content' that you have refrerred in HTML and IF condiition

Comment: You have the code on my question `<ion-content>`

Comment: without TS file can't help. content you are trying to use for scrolling is ionic content but you are trying to access some data in HTML which is confusing. using the following content you can scroll up and down import {  Content } from 'ionic-angular';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159650/discussion-between-stuart2041-and-prithivi-raj).